# Cannot import pixi.js to .ts file

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I am new to pixi.js. I am trying to use it for the first time, so I installed it through `npm install pixi.js --save-dev` and even though it added the pixi.js dependancy to my package.json, it doesn't work when trying to import it. For some reason pixi.js is not found in the node_modules folder either.
I have tried uninstalling the package and then reinstalling but still it is not found in node_modules.

Something to note is that I have tried importing the DefinetlyTyped version of pixi.js which I have also installed through npm, but that version lacked some definitions of pixi.js this is why I'd need the original pixi.js to be imported into my TypeScript project. Is it even possible to work with .js libraries through TypeScript? (I think I should be since TypeScript is able to work with JavaScript code as well)

I have tried importing pixi as:
`import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';`
`import PIXI from 'pixi.js';`
`var PIXI = require('pixi');`
`var PIXI = require('pixi.js');`

I am trying to access pixi.js from app.ts that is in a folder called 'ts-src' that is outside of node_modules, could that be the issue? (I don't think so but had to ask it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have installed pixi.js then make sure that you have installed @types/pixi.js package too which provides type definition for pixi.js. Now when you have pixi.js as in dependencies. Then only thing remaining is to include pixi.js in HTML as

```
<script src="../node_modules/pixi.js/dist/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

Now in your app.ts, you would be able to do something like

```
import { Application, Point } from 'pixi.js';
//.....Some code    
const point = new Point(10, 20);
```

If you having trouble in using some pixi.js components though type definition. Then create an index.ts file in your source folder and update it with

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
export { PIXI };
```

Now in your app code, you can do this directly

```
const label = new PIXI.Graphics();
```

Comment: PixiJS has now moved to Typescript so installing `@types/pixi.js` shouldn't be necessary.